# Roslyn Doesn't Publish to Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roslyn

I recently updated the Nuget package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform to 1.0.7. After that it stopped publishing Roslyn to the website. I would then get the error 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:...\bin\roslyn\csc.exe' when I tried to access the website.

I works fine when I run the website from Visual Studio. Also, I noticed it also isn't copying Roslyn to the temp folder it creates before publishing to the website.

I reverted to 1.0.6 and it published rolsyn to the website and resumed working. I tried 1.0.7 again and it stop publishing rolsyn again.

I would like to get the latest version working. Is there something I need to do to get it to work? Or is there someone wrong with 1.0.7 and I should wait for the next version?

Also, this is happening in both of the projects I've tried updating.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to 1.0.8 should fix the issue.

Looks like publish issues started in 1.0.6 ([Roslyn binaries not copied properly on publish in 1.0.6](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/13)).

The publish issues were still not resolved in 1.0.7 ([Publish issue in 1.0.7 release](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/17) ).  Finally, everything appears to work in 1.0.8.

Comment: Geez, I created my project in 2019 and it still had this problem and was using version 1.0.7 by default.  Lame MS.